# AWS S3: How to receive notifications about create/delete objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

Is it possible to receive notifications in a .NET Core application about bucket/object creation/deletion?
How to do it?

Comment: Where is the .NET Core application running? On a server, or is it an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: It is Blazor Net Core Server-side Web application (cross-platform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon S3 Events can send a notification to:

- **An AWS Lambda function (Trigger):** Does not appear relevant since your code is running elsewhere.
- **An Amazon SQS queue (Pull):** Your application could regularly poll the Amazon SQS queue to retrieve a message, then act on that message.
- **An Amazon SNS topic (Push):** Your application could subscribe to the Amazon SNS topic to receive the message via an HTTP endpoint. For example, this could point to your back-end web server.

If your application has a web server that is accessible from the Internet, then use the SNS push. Otherwise, your app will need to poll the SQS queue.

Answer (score 2):

S3 bucket can generate SNS and SQS [event notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html) as well as trigger Lambda function on misc. events. Go to Bucket Properties->Events.

In your .NET code you'll need to react to these events, for instance by [receiving SQS messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/ReceiveMessage.html).

[image: S3 Event configuration]

Comment: Can I change settings from the application? and then receive the notifications in the app?

Comment: PutBucketNotificationConfiguration API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketNotificationConfiguration.html will let you do it from the application. There is .NET SDK too. You might need to use another one for configuring SNS or SQS related settings.